# UWP - XDocument Equivalent Of XMLNodeList

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

If I had an XMLDocument and wanted to for example count the number of results of a Node I would use something like

```
        //XmlNodeList CountResultsReturned = XMLSearch.SelectNodes("root/item");
        //if (CountResultsReturned.Count > 1)
        //{}
```

I was wondering how I would achive something like this using XDocument instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no specific class in LINQ to XML which is equivalent to XmlNodeList, because LINQ to XML simply works with sequence of nodes `IEnumerable<XNode>` or sequence of elements `IEnumerable<XElement>`. When you select some nodes it just yields matching nodes one by one. You can store sequence to list or other collection, if you want to. E.g

```
var items = xdoc.Root.Elements("item").ToList();
```

For your code just select elements and use LINQ `Any()` method to check if any elements exist:

```
xdoc.Root.Elements("item").Any()
// items.Any()
```

You can also use `Count()` to get number of elements. Of course XPath also available

```
xdoc.XPathSelectElements("root/item").Count()
// items.Count
```

Comment: I'm trying to convert my application to UWP and it really doesn't like the XML I currently have,I feel like I should maybe do some more reading on XDocuments. Using your code seems to be doing what I wanted so thank you and I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: @TLCONE LINQ to XML is a good choice. I suggest you to read some tutorial and/or try it with LINQ Pad. There is *Samples* tab where you can find C# 6 LINQ to XML tutorial